# Redux - are there any drawback to using bindActionCreators in the constructor of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have seen lots of examples using the `bindActionCreators` function in the `mapDispatchToProps` function like so:

```
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators({
        doSomething: somethingActions.doSomething,
    }, dispatch)
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent);
```

This means that every time store changes, this component will update and re-execute wrapping the `somethingActions.doSomething` action creator in the `dispatch` function and returning that as an anonymous function.

Wouldn't it be more performant to simply do this once in the constructor like so ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { dispatch } = props;

    this.boundActionCreators = bindActionCreators({
        doSomething: somethingActions.doSomething,
    }, dispatch);
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing this?

Answer (score 3):

`mapDispatchToProps` is on default used only once per component life cycle - [see this question in Redux GitHub](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/563). It can run multiple times, theoretically causing performance issues.

### Things that can cause troubles:

- Splitting of concerns - having `mapDispatchToProps` as separate function that is passed to `connect()` HOC helps with future refactoring - it is easy to move the connection anywhere else, extend it or remove it completely - without any change in component alone. [See this article from Dan Abramov about Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). In this case, your component is Presentational and `connect()` + it's `mapDispatchToProps` is Container.
- Code redeability - constructor can become quite long and messy - imagine having to use `boundActionCreators` 10 times.
- Usage of `actions` - with your solution, you need to do `this.nameOfAction()` to dispatch action to redux. But for fetching data, you would do `this.props.nameOfDataProp`. Having same way how to access all `Redux` functionalities (aka via `props`) can help with redeability and maintenance.
- Also the performace boost would be discutable - since `mapDispatchToProps` is used multiple times only when it depends on `props`. I would encourage you to test this in your app to see if you can get good enought perfomance boost.

TL;DR: You can get some minor performance boost, but for a big price in terms of code maintenance and redeability.

Comment: Yep.  `mapDispatch` runs once on component creation, unless you use the `ownProps` argument.  My advice is to use the "object shorthand" and pass an object full of action creators to `connect`, which shortens things.

Comment: Could you give an example of the "object shorthand" you mention?